# Why chart does not change based on the chosen?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, charts

I am trying to show the chart inside website using spring MVC and JSP. 
I have succeeded to show the chart. But, now I just want to show the type of chart (e.g.: pie/bar/line, so on), by providing the "select drop down option". 
The Idea is, once I choose the option inside the drop-down menu. The chart will show up based on what I chose. For example, if I choose the bar It should show the bar chart.

But in the reality, When I run the website on the first time (pre-condition: the select drop-down with "bar" option as a default), it can show the chart as well. But, when I tried to change the type of chart, the result did not change as what I choose. It still shows the bar chart.

This is the JSP code:

```
<select id="typeChart" class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-khaki" onchange="changeTypeChart(this);">
    <option value="pie">Pie</option>
    <option value="column" selected="selected">Bar</option>
    <option value="line">Line</option>
</select>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

<input type="button" value="Save PNG" class="button" id="btn-download" />
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var typeChart1;
var selectedValue;
var dataPoints = [];
window.onload = function() {

    var title_file = document.getElementById("titleFile").innerHTML;
    var blob = document.getElementById('ini').innerHTML;
    console.log("blob " +  blob);



    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: title_file
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Index PA",
            includeZero: true
        },
        axisX: {
            title: "Time",
        },
        data: [{
            type: selectedValue,
            toolTipContent: "{y} stat index",
            dataPoints: dataPoints
        }]
    });

    changeTypeChart(blob, chart);



}
function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv, chart) {
    if (csv != null){
        console.log("ini di fc");
        // console.log(csv);
        var points;
        var csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);
        for (var i = 2; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
            if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
                points = csvLines[i].split(";");
                // console.log(points[12]);
                dataPoints.push({
                    label: points[2],
                    y: parseFloat(points[12])
                });
            }
        }

        chart.render();
    }else{
        console.log("csv is not get");
    }
}
function changeTypeChart(blob, chart){
    typeChart1 = document.getElementById("typeChart");
    selectedValue = typeChart1.options[typeChart1.selectedIndex].value;

    console.log("this is type chart : "  + selectedValue);
    getDataPointsFromCSV(blob, chart);
}
```

And I also got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at new S (canvasjs.min.js:133)
    at q._initialize (canvasjs.min.js:171)
    at q.render (canvasjs.min.js:177)
    at getDataPointsFromCSV (act:20185)
    at changeTypeChart (act:20195)
    at window.onload (act:20163)
```

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are invoking changeTypeChart() when the selection is changed but the logic to render the chart is outside changeTypeChart()

Comment: According to your logic the render is happening only when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. You are right. It works now. But when I run first, the page shows a blank chart. I should change the options chart, and it can show the result afterward.  Do  you have idea how to make the chart can show first even i have not select anything? @PaWa